# PL/SQL passing parameters as hidden input to another procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL.

I have an HTML form which was generated by PL/SQL procedure similar to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SAMPLE_P 
(I_CUSTOMER_ID in varchar2,
I_PRODUCT_CODE in varchar2)

AS
--var declarations here...
 htp.p('html head body tags here...');

 htp.p('<form action="SAMPLE_B" method="post" name="sample_form" enctype="text/plain">');

 htp.p('<input type="hidden" value="'||i_customer_id||'" name="i_customer_id">
        <input type="hidden" value="'||i_product_code||'" name="i_product_code">');

 htp.p('submit button and all the ending html tags here');
```

And my sample_b procedure looks similar to:

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE SAMPLE_B(
 i_customer_id in varchar2,
 i_product_code IN VARCHAR2)
 AS

 BEGIN
 htp.p('<html><head></head><body><h1>cust id = '||i_customer_id||'</h1><br><h1>product 
 ='||i_product_code||'</h1> <br> </body><html>');

 END SAMPLE_B;
```

The problem with this code is that when I click on submit button I get an error page saying that i_product_code does not exist in the form. When I set i_product_code default to null  in sample_b I get no error but in my new generated page cust id is equal to customer id value followed by product code value and product code is null. Looks like instead of single value I got all values in first variable and nothing was sent via second variable. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please note some lines of code have been omitted to keep the code shorter.

Comment: The documentation explicitly refers to [using hidden fields](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_web.htm#ADFNS499) like this. Have you looked at the generated HTML to see if it's structured as you expect - you don't have mismatched quotes somewhere, for example? (And is there a reason you're doing this manually rather than using [`FORMHIDDEN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/w_htp.htm#ARPLS391)?)

Comment: I have checked my HTML code many times to see if I have made any mistakes with no results. Also I am using SQL Developer which would highlight any obvious errors, but it doesn't. htp.Formhidden as far as I understand is just a function that generates hidden input, I could try it but I would be very surprised if that would solve my problem.

Comment: If your code is correct then it won't make any difference, no; but as it does the quoting etc. it can help avoid mistakes. Changing at this point won't make any difference, I agree. Unless you rewrite the whole procedure to use those tools. Also SQL Developer wouldn't warn you about mismatched double-quotes within strings, which is what I meant. That sort of problem should be fairly obvious in generated code. We can't see that, of course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was form attribute enctype, when that is removed the problem disappears.